# UDP sending two strings in a datagram

Tags: linux, java, udp

I'm wondering if its possible to send two strings within one datagram in a UDP packet. Assume I had string 1 with text: unix and string 2 with text: linux. I don't want to merge the strings but keep them separate when there transferred

This is my working code that succesfully reads on the server unix

```
 String name1 = "unix"; 
    String name2 = "linux"; 
                toSend = name1.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket packSend = new DatagramPacket (toSend, toSend.length, ipConn, 9876); 
                connection.send(packSend);
```

Would it be wise two create 2 separate datagram packets and send the data separately?

Comment: Looks like you're using Java.  Added the Java tag accordingly.  Please add your language to the tags yourself next time.

Comment: At the moment, you can do this by hand.  But as soon as it gets complex, you might want to consider a serialization protocol such as [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to serialize the data somehow, either by using a common format (xml, json, uuencode, ...) or by using any separator that may not occur in your strings (newline, ...) and then simply splitting that string.

If you send them separately, be aware that either packet may be lost, or received in different order, etc. So if this data is related at all, it makes quite a lot of sense to send it in a single packet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep them separate you need two packets, but it is more efficient to transmit them inside a single packet and then split the packet in the receiver.